# Compare nulll value with non null value SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two columns as below:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | NULL |
| A1 | A1 |
| B1 | C1. |

When i query these columns as below :

SELECT Column A, Column B
from table
where Column A != Column B

i am expecting the following result:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | NULL |
| B1. | C1 |

But my query is only giving me the second line as result.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean that only the second row is being returned?

Comment: Also, is that value in Column B "null." or NULL?

Comment: Look into `is distinct from`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider below

```
select *
from your_table
where columnA is distinct from columnB
```

with output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

null in SQL equals unknown

It could also have A1 as value, therefore it will not show up if you check if A1 is not null

Comment: This doesnt work , i have tried it already

Answer (score 0):

Null values do not participate in equality operations as there is no value to compare with.

You will need to include a check for null into your comparisoon statement.

```
SELECT Column A, Column B from table where  ISNULL(Column A,0) <> ISNULL(Column B,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from Your_table
where IFNULL(`Column A`, 'NULL') != IFNULL(`Column B`, 'NULL')
```

`IFNULL(expression, alt_value)` function returns the value of the `expression` if it's not `NULL` and returns `alt_value` when `expression` is `NULL`.
So, from the above query, `Column A` and `Column B` will have the string value of `'NULL'` when the column has the `NULL` value so they can still be comparable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below workaround

```
select * from your_table
except distinct
select * from your_table
where columnA = columnB
```

with output

[image]